# Django Query to get count of all distinct values for column of ArrayField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

What is the most efficient way to count all distinct values for column of ArrayField.
Let's suppose I have a model with the name `MyModel` and `cities` field which is postgres.ArrayField.

```
#models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
     ....
     cities = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),blank=True,null=True,default=list) ### ['mumbai','london']
```

and let's suppose our `MyModel` has the following 3 objects with  `cities` field value as follow.

```
1. ['london','newyork']
2. ['mumbai']
3. ['london','chennai','mumbai']
```

- Doing a count on distinct values for `cities` field does on the entire list instead of doing on each element.

```
## Query
MyModel.objects.values('cities').annotate(Count('id')).order_by().filter(id__count__gt=0)
```

---

- Here I would like to count distinct values for `cities` field on each element of the list of `cities` field.which should give the following final output.

```
[{'london':2},{'newyork':1},{'chennai':1},{'mumbai':2}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perform the ***group by operation in the database level itself***.

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
raw_query = """
select unnest(subquery_alias.cities) as distinct_cities, count(*) as cities_group_by_count
    from (select cities from sample_mymodel) as subquery_alias group by distinct_cities;
"""

cursor.execute(raw_query)
result = [{"city": row[0], "count": row[1]} for row in cursor]
print(result)
```

#### References

1. [**`unnest()`-postgress array function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html)
2. [Django: Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with an in-efficient way out of Django syllabus:

```
    unique_cities = list(data.values_list('cities',flat=True))
    unique_cities_compiled = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(unique_cities ))
    unique_cities_final = {unique_cities_compiled .count(i) for i in unique_cities_compiled }
    print(unique_cities_final )
```

```
{'london':2},{'newyork':1},{'chennai':1},{'mumbai':2}
```

- if anyone does in much efficient way, do drop the answer for the improvised version of the solution.